# how to convert Hex String to ASCII String in KOTLIN

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I receive on my application with a BLE module a hexagonal String
[Hex string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MEFF.png)

> 0031302D31300D0A

This string in ASCII is **10-10\r\n** (which represents the coordinates of the **x** axis and the **y** axis).
I tried to use the toCharArray function to convert to ASCII in an array and have the possibility to parse the string and get the x and y values but it returns a string like this in the logcat [C@3cea859

I also tried to create a function but it returns the same type of string

```
fun String.decodeHex(): ByteArray{
        check(length % 2 == 0){"Must have an even length"}
        return chunked(2)
            .map { it.toInt(16).toByte() }
            .toByteArray()
    }
```

Comment: String hex = "0031302D31300D0A"; Please tell what x and y would be. String xhex = ... String yhex = ....

Comment: @blackapps xhex = 3130, separatorHex = 2D, yhex = 3130 endCharacHex = 0D0A

Comment: You mean xhex = "3130". A string. If you dont have a string at start (like i used in my comment) but a byte array  of 8 bytes then please state so in your post.

Comment: yes @blackapps i mean xhex = "3130", separatorHex = "2D", yhex = "3130" endCharacHex = "0D0A"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly there. You just need to convert the ByteArray to a String. The standard `toString()` method comes from type `Any` (equivalent to Java's `Object`). The ByteArray doesn't override it to give you what you want. Instead, use the `String` constructor or the `toString(Charset)` function:

```
fun String.decodeHex(): String {
    require(length % 2 == 0) {"Must have an even length"}
    return chunked(2)
        .map { it.toInt(16).toByte() }
        .toByteArray()
        .toString(Charsets.ISO_8859_1)  // Or whichever encoding your input uses
}
```

(Note also that `require` is more appropriate than `check` in that context.)

Comment: Hey, I convert the byte array to a string with the toString function and get nothing on logcat.  `fun String.decodeHex(): String{
        require(length % 2 == 0){"Must have an even length"}
        return String(chunked(2)
            .map { it.toInt(16).toByte() }
            .toByteArray())
    }`  // output : nothing

Comment: Are you actually calling it? Something like `log(hexString.decodeHex())`?

Comment: @P.C You can see it working here: https://pl.kotl.in/xMdOUuqfG

Comment: @P.C one possible issue is that the string starts with hex 00 which results in a '\0' character at the beginning of the string, which maybe the logger doesn't like.

Comment: Yes i call it `Log.i("sensor", hexstring.decodHex())` and the only thing I have is this `2022-03-30 11:22:56.397 2016-2016/com.example.lightrdetect D/sensor: `

Comment: I tried to add a prefix like "110031302D31300D0A", but nothing appears in the logger.

Comment: `Hey, I convert the byte array to a string with the toString function` ??? You have no byte array . You said you had a hex string. This is all now very confusing . Please rewrite your post and tell on the first line what you have.

Comment: the first decoHex function I created, returns a conversion of a hexadecimal string into an array of bytes and then I converted the array of bytes into a string. @blackapps

Comment: If you really receive a string, and this string is a hexadecimal notation then i can understand that you convert it to eight bytes in a byte array. But why would you convert that byte array to a string again? Makes no sense to me. And what would be the string? Remember you said you started with String hex = "0031302D31300D0A";. Then how would the string look then?

Comment: And if String xhex ="3030" then why not just decode that to x == 12336? That would be the value of x i understood. If not then its clear you did not explain enough of what you receive.

Comment: @blackapps the OP stated in his question that it's hex to ASCII (and even gave an example). If it was 0x3030 treated as a 16-bit number and converted to 12336 as you said, that's not ASCII. In ASCII, every character is 7 bits (though 8 bits are usually used for convenience) and in the example given, "3130" is converted into "\u0031\u0030".

Comment: This does not work correctly with special characters. 
Something like this won't work: `45726E6575740A5072E473656E74696572656E`